# awk: Split on "\n"

Tags: awk

I'm trying to process a log file in which entries are compressed into one line with the newline encoded as "\n". I want to keep everything up to the first "\n" and discard the rest. `awk -F"\n" '{print $1}' file` doesn't work, and neither does `awk -F"\\n" '{print $1}' file`. What's the correct form of this command?

Comment: `NR == 1 { print $0 }` maybe. It would help to give some examples as to what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: Try `awk -F '\\\\n'`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo 'a\nb'
a\nb

$ echo 'a\nb' | awk -F'\\\\n' '{print $1}'
a
```

Here's why: Consider these uses of the above characters in regexp comparisons:

- `n`    = the literal character `n` (`$0 ~ /n/`)
- `\n`   = a literal newline character (`$0 ~ /\n/`)
- `\\`   = a backslash when used in a regexp constant (`$0 ~ /\\/`)
- `\\\\` = a backslash when used in a dynamic regexp (`$0 ~ "\\\\"`)

That last one is because a dynamic regexp is a string which has to be parsed once to be converted to a regexp and then gets parsed again when used as that regexp, so since it gets parsed twice it needs all escapes to be doubled.

Since a field separator is basically a regexp (with a few twists) when you say `-F "whatever"` you are defining the FS variable to be a dynamic regexp and so escapes have to be doubled.