# Remove \ " and \n using sed

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

How to replace the below text using sed or in any other method.

```
"Revert \"Release 1.0.0\"\n\nThis reverts commit"
```

I need to replace the above to be like

```
"Revert Release 1.0.0 This reverts commit"
```

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: sed -e :a -e N -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'`  I tried this however it will replace the last line with the space but not the in between texts.

Comment: Is your original text is in a file? Do you have literal `\n` there or actual newlines?

Comment: I have literal \n there. The org text mentioned above.  "Revert \"Release 1.0.0\"\n\nThis reverts commit"

Comment: please don't add relevant info in the comments. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63986478/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\` or `.` needs to be escaped in regex pattern.

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/"Revert \\"Release 1\.0\.0\\"\\n\\nThis reverts commit"/"Revert Release 1.0.0 This reverts commit"/' file
```

```
"Revert Release 1.0.0 This reverts commit"
```

---

You may consider this `awk` to remove `\"` and `\n` characters anywhere in the file:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]*(\\["n])+/, " ")} 1' file
```

```
"Revert Release 1.0.0 This reverts commit"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
sed -E 's/\\"//g;s/(\\n)+/ /' <<<'"Revert \"Release 1.0.0\"\n\nThis reverts commit"'
```

The `\"`'s are removed and one or more `\n`'s are replaced by a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Also using `awk`, we can test

```
awk -v FS='\\\\["n]' -v OFS= '{print $1,$2,$5}' file
"Revert Release 1.0.0This reverts commit"
```

and with `printf` we have the desired result:

```
awk -v FS='\\\\["n]' -v OFS= '{printf "%s%s %s", $1,$2,$5}{print ""}' file
"Revert Release 1.0.0 This reverts commit"
```

This code:

- the backslash used in the regexp`\\\\` for literal `\` Here, Ed Morton gives a detailed explication:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925553
- We use `printf` to add the space between fields `$2` and `$5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Node on you system you can do a

```
rexreplace ' *(§§["n])+ *' ' ' file.txt
```

by installing globally first `npm -i rexreplace -g` or prepending the command with `npx`